# Protractor JS- Filtering Arraylist & replacing duplicate word

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am automating a scenario in which i get list of elements store it in an array, I need to remove the repeating word "teniss" from the array.

Till yet i am able to fetch the elements & trying to use the if condition to achieve it.

```
 var lists=element.all(By.css(".entity-link>a"));
        lists.getText().then(function(text){
              console.log("The list contents are "+text);     
          }
        for (var i=0; i<40;){

          if (lists.get(i) === 'teniss')
            {
               lists.get(i)=="";
            }
i++;
            }
```

output of the map function:

```
[ { index: 0, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 1, text: 'ARTICLE 1' },
      { index: 2, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 3, text: 'ARTICLE 2' },
      { index: 4, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 5, text: 'ARTICLE 3' },
      { index: 6, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 7, text: 'ARTICLE 4' },
      { index: 8, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 9, text: 'ARTICLE 5' },
      { index: 10, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 11, text: 'ARTICLE 6' },
      { index: 12, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 13, text: 'ARTICLE 7' },
      { index: 14, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 15, text: 'ARTICLE 8' },
      { index: 16, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 17, text: 'ARTICLE 9' },
      { index: 18, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 19, text: 'ARTICLE 10' },
      { index: 20, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 21, text: 'ARTICLE 11' },
      { index: 22, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 23, text: 'ARTICLE 12' },
      { index: 24, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 25, text: 'ARTICLE 13' },
      { index: 26, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 27, text: 'ARTICLE 14' },
      { index: 28, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 29, text: 'ARTICLE 15' },
      { index: 30, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 31, text: 'ARTICLE 16' },
      { index: 32, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 33, text: 'ARTICLE 17' },
      { index: 34, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 35, text: 'ARTICLE 18' },
      { index: 36, text: 'teniss' },
      { index: 37, text: 'teniss' },
  { index: 38, text: 'teniss' } ]
```

Comment: Where are you sttuck?

Comment: In the for loop, its not replacing the element with word 'teniss' to ''.

Comment: Can you share url ?

Comment: `lists.get(i)` is grabbing the ElementFinder, not the text from that element

Comment: Also, why don't you use the `filter()` function?  That's what it's for, to filter results based on a certain criteria

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? A for loop with promises, and not handling them properly, is never a good idea. If you want to return an filtered array with the result as text you can also use [map](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) ] and true, the `lists.get(i)` will only give you an ElementFinder. To get the text you first need to resolve the promise with `getText()`

Comment: Using the map function i can get the list of elements but after getting the list i need to modify the list and refine it by deleting the word 'teniss' & then retrieve & print the refined list, thats where the tricky part is...

Comment: Added the map functions output result, from the result i only need to retrieve the odd number indexes which don't have the text as 'teniss'